# Why do these generics work only if I store class in a separate variable?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface and method that returns the interface:

```
public static interface TagMaker<T> {
    public Tag makeTag(String name, T object);
}
//Tags convert the given object to be able to be put in a certain file format.
private static final Map<Class, TagMaker> tagMakers = new HashMap<>();
public static <T> void registerTagMaker(Class<T> clazz, TagMaker<? super T> tagMaker) {
    tagMakers.put(clazz, tagMaker);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> TagMaker<? super T> getTagMaker(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) return null;
    Class<? super T> candidate = Object.class;
    for (Class c : tagMakers.keySet()) {
        if (c.isAssignableFrom(clazz) && candidate.isAssignableFrom(c)) {//prefer more specific classes; for horizontal relations, choose at random
            candidate = c;
        }
    }
    return tagMakers.get(candidate);
}
```

I'm trying get the TagMaker corresponding to an arbitrary Object and use it to make a tag. Why is it that this works

```
Class clazz = object.getClass();
return getTagMaker(clazz).makeTag(name, object);
```

but this throws a compile-time error?

```
return getTagMaker(object.getClass()).makeTag(name, object);
/* results in
error: method makeTag in interface TagMaker<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        return getTagMaker(object.getClass()).makeTag(name, object);
  required: String,CAP#1
  found: String,Object
reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface TagMaker
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: CAP#2 from capture of ? super CAP#2
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
*/
```

Comment: Your code gives a warning instead; you're bypassing generics entirely.

Comment: @SLaks How would I do it so that it doesn't bypass generics? It's clearly safe short of another thread changing object, since it always finds a TagMaker that accepts a superclass of object's class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should require an explicit cast because Java's generics can't distinguish between

```
getTagMaker(object.getClass()).makeTag(name, object); //always safe
//and
getTagMaker(object.getClass()).makeTag(name, new Object()); //usually unsafe
```

Any code which would make the first line not require a cast or warning would also permit the second, unsafe line. Proper usage of generics is to generate and suppress a warning when doing an operation that you can prove to be safe, but which Java cannot:

```
final TagMaker tagMaker = getTagMaker(object.getClass()); //implied cast TagMaker<? super ?> -> TagMaker
if (tagMaker != null) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Tag tag = tagMaker.makeTag(name, object);
    return tag;
}
```

Comment: I don't follow this. In your first code block, what is the type of `object`? Let's assume it's some type A. Then `getTagMaker(object.getClass())` returns either `TagMaker<A>` or `TagMaker<? super A>` depending upon whether you follow my or SLaks' suggestion. In either case calling `makeTag(name, object)` works but `makeTag(name, new Object())` is an error. In your second code block you assign to a raw `TagMaker` which loses type checking. I don't think it's necessary to assign to a raw type though.

Comment: @StuartMarks The type of object is Object, thus providing a TagMaker<Object>, even though the tag maker may not accept Objects.

Comment: Hm, interesting. It seems like this is a mismatch between the static typing system (generics) and the runtime type. Either you could make sure they stay in synch, perhaps by migrating your second code block above into your library, so callers can't get it wrong; or you could add runtime type checking to each TagMaker instance, perhaps by wrapping the registered ones.

Comment: @StuartMarks They can't stay in sync because they never were in sync: all relation to the original object is forgotten when getClass() is called (returns <? extends Object>, useless), and the method never sees the object. I could make a getTagMaker(T object) function, or I could also just leave it where it acts like the Map which it wraps and SuppressWarnings when I need to.

Comment: If the static type of references being handed to getTagMaker is Object, then generics can't help you at all, since they're purely statically typed. You might as well change TagMaker not to be a generic type, since its type parameter *T* will only ever be based on the static type of what's handed in, which is Object. If you take out the generics, there will be no raw or unchecked warnings at all. If you want any checking it'll have to be dynamic.

Comment: @StuartMarks The generics enforce the contract for registerTagMaker, which is necessary, and specify the contract for getTagMaker (enforced with Class.isAssignableFrom()), which is important in code maintainability. In fact, in my final version, I have made getTagMaker public, so having the generics there is important.

Answer (score 3):

Your example has:

```
private static <T> TagMaker<? super T> getTagMaker(Class<T> clazz)
```

Is that right? Given a class instance representing some type *T*, it returns a `TagMaker` for some arbitrary supertype of *T*? I don't know what your application is, but that doesn't make much sense to me. Perhaps this declaration can be rewritten as follows:

```
private static <T> TagMaker<T> getTagMaker(Class<? extends T> clazz)
```

Then you can write:

```
return getTagMaker(object.getClass()).makeTag(name, object);
```

If the type of object is `SomeType`, then the type of object.getClass() is `Class<? extends SomeType>`, the *T* type arg of getTagMaker() is inferred to be `SomeType`, and getTagMaker() returns `TagMaker<SomeType>`. This compiles without errors or warnings.

Unless I've completely misunderstood what you're trying to do....

---

**UPDATE**

Well, the OP has added some helpful context and has already accepted [SLaks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20453637/1441122) but I'll post some additional suggestions here in the hope that either the OP or someone else will find them useful.

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, TagMaker<?>> tagMakers = new HashMap<>();
```

I've changed this declaration from raw types to unbounded wildcards just to keep things within the generic type system. This is an interesting case, reminiscent of the "Type-safe Heterogenous Container" described in Bloch's *Effective Java* item 29. The point is that the relationship between the keys and values can't be described using Java's generics.

```
// original
public static <T> void registerTagMaker(Class<T> clazz, TagMaker<? super T> tagMaker) {
    tagMakers.put(clazz, tagMaker);
}

// my suggestion
public static <T> void registerTagMaker(Class<? extends T> clazz, TagMaker<T> tagMaker) {
    tagMakers.put(clazz, tagMaker);
}
```

Either of these will work, since it establishes the required relationship between a class and the TagMaker for that class. The question is which way you want to think of *T*. In fact it doesn't matter, since this type relationship is thrown away when the items are put into the Map, which is completely wildcarded.

```
private static <T> TagMaker<T> getTagMaker(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) return null;
    Class<?> candidate = Object.class;
    for (Class<?> c : tagMakers.keySet()) {
        if (c.isAssignableFrom(clazz) && candidate.isAssignableFrom(c)) {//prefer more specific classes; for horizontal relations, choose at random
            candidate = c;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TagMaker<T> result = (TagMaker<T>)tagMakers.get(candidate);
    return result;
}
```

I've done several things here. First, I've changed the clazz argument to `Class<? extends T>` and the return type to `TagMaker<T>`. Second, I've changed the local variables to be `Class<?>`. This code is making a bunch of assertions about the type relationships of values being used here which I don't think are expressible in the generic type system, so using `Class<? super T>` for the locals doesn't do anything except add warnings. Finally, I've put in a cast for the value retrieved from the map. This is the line that generates a warning, so I've assigned it to a local and added the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation (which can only be added to declarations). This is safe, since it relies on the relationship of items put into the map by registerTagMaker().

Why not return `TagMaker<? super T>`? This will work, and it's correct (at least, it's not incorrect) but it makes the API confusing, and I don't think it adds any value. Consider the original TagMaker definition:

```
public static interface TagMaker<T> {
    public Tag makeTag(String name, T object);
}
```

This means you can call makeTag with *T* or any subtype of *T*. Now let's use the version of getTagMaker() that returns `TagMaker<? super T>`:

```
TagMaker<? super Foo> tmfoo = getTagMaker(Foo.class);
tmfoo.makeTag("", ???);
```

What can I pass as the second argument to makeTag()? I can pass anything that is a subtype of some unknown supertype of Foo. In practice, this means I can only pass something of type Foo or a subtype of Foo. So returning `TagMaker<? super Foo>` doesn't help the caller at all, so you might as well return `TagMaker<Foo>` instead. In my opinion it's much clearer.

Comment: Tags are a means of storing data in a particular file format. My class has a basic makeTag function for primitives, etc, and if that function can't turn that class of object into a tag, it looks through tagMakers that other classes have provided to find one that is capable of processing the object. Would just make Taggable an interface, but a lot of the classes needing to be made into tags are  coded by other people. I'll post the code for getTagMaker, I'm not sure how rewriting it to ? extends T would change it functionally.

Comment: Actually, `TagMaker<? super T>` makes perfect sense.  If it can take a supertype of `T`, it can also take `T`.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense in isolation, but in context I think it's confusing. See my update.

Comment: After first reading the answer i gave +1 to @StuartMarks, then read all of the answer :). I think Stuart Marks has a valid reasoning here.

Comment: If I use your code and type getTagMaker(object.getClass()), then use Netbeans Assign Return Value to New Variable, it infers TagMaker<Object> as the class of the result. But, I don't want to just get a TagMaker<Object>; I usually want a TagMaker of a subclass of Object...Hm, SLaks's solution infers to TagMaker<? super Object>, which is just silly, so I guess this is better. Still, with either solution, getTagMaker(object.getClass()).makeTag(name, new Object()) is valid, which it shouldn't be, so casting and suppressing the warning might actually be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Change your signature to

```
private static <T> TagMaker<? super T> getTagMaker(Class<? extends T> clazz)
```

This works fine.

Comment: +1 for finding a way to make it work. But I think it can be improved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `object.getClass()` is `public final Class<? extends Object> getClass()`, use a cast to erase the signature and your other example works.

```
return getTagMaker((Class) object.getClass()).makeTag(name, object);
```

Comment: Actually, `getClass()` ha a magic signature; it returns `Class<? extends X>`, where `X` is the compile-time type of the qualifier.